# Does Bash for Windows create an own desktop?

Tags: login, .desktop, windows-subsystem-for-linux, prompt

I downloaded Bash (Ubuntu 18.04) for Windows 10 yesterday and created my account, downloaded a couple of files there. i closed the prompt, now when i open it, it starts from System32 folder i got back to find my normal windows desktop. What happened to my other files? does ubuntu create a new clean desktop or does it only open mine? 
when i first logged in and made the account there was not one folder there so i figured that it was a new clean desktop, how do i go back to that one? do i have to sign in ? if so, how do i do that? thanks.

Comment: type `cd ~` to go to your home folder. Then use `ls` to see your subdirectories and files.

Comment: Did it work for you to find your files downloaded in previous session?

Comment: What do you mean by "desktop" here? WSL don't have any GUI support officially. From question, it looks like you're asking for home folder.

Comment: WinEunuuchs2Unix, Yes, i was able to find the files, thanks a lot.                                                         -Biswapriyo, I thought the application created a new desktop, but it seems that wasn't the case, you are right, i was indeed looking for the home folder, thanks.